# django - app not in INSTALLED_APPS but its views.py is running

Tags: python, django

I having multiple apps. I want to run them according to settings.py which means I have multiple settings_x.py. I run server e.g. like this:

```
python manage.py runserver --settings=myproj.settings_1.py
```

for app1.

If I run

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it should take the default settings.py where I didnot define any app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, and It should give me error saying, that the module app1 doesnot exist because of

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('app1.views',#<---- app1 isn't in the settings.py
   url(r'^$', 'startpage', name='startpage'),
)
```

But it is going to `startpage` function inside `app1.views`.

why is this? am I missing something?

Comment: are you sure your wsgi.py file is pointing to the correct default setting file? in the line `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` ?

Comment: @GabrielAmram i am in local dev server, but wsgi is really showing to default settings.py.

Comment: Yes, I should have figured out that you're in a local env. Is this setting also true in the `manage.py` file?

Comment: @GabrielAmram yep, in manage.py also showing to settings.py which doesnot have the app1 in it. i thought, if i remove app from settings.py, app will be completely off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason why it wouldn't. Views can come from anywhere, and don't have to be in an app at all: they just need to be accessible from the Python path.

Comment: Oh, I didnot know that. I want to use different views for url ``/test/`` depending on apps in settings.py, how can I do it?

Comment: I just need to override the ``ROOT_URLCONF`` to show to different urls.py, right?

Answer (score 1):

Go to a non-existing url (`http://localhost:8000/ksjfklsdfj`) and django should give you a list of valid URL patterns, perhaps that gives you a hint?

Also `manage.py diffsettings` gives you a list of settings as Django sees it. This might also tell you if you've somehow mixed up something.