# django - how to disable apps

Tags: django, django-apps

I have multiple settings_x.py

I want to disable `app1` which is inside `INSTALLED_APPS` of one settings_1.py

I tried to comment the app, but the app is still avalaible from urls.py.

how can I do this? I dont want to delete, I just want to turn off the app.

Comment: Just comment out the url mapping.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I tested that way by NOT commenting out to see if it gives me error smthing like ``module doesnot exist`` but it is going thru to apps.views.. here is my following question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604537/django-app-not-in-installed-apps-but-its-views-py-is-running sorry for posting links

Answer (score 3):

in urls.py of project ,import settings of project.

```
from django.conf import settings
```

in urls.py of project, add this code.

```
 if 'app1' in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
    urlpatterns += url(r'^app1/', include('app1.urls'), name='app1'),
```

if you add this code, system will check if the app is added to INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py or not. If it does not exist, system will not add its urls.py configurations and also the urls of app will not work.

Comment: You should never reference settings.INSTALLED_APPS directly, since local settings can overwrite it or it can be modified dynamically. Instead, you can use `from django.apps import apps` and then `if apps.is_installed('app_name')`

Answer (score 2):

Apps are available even though they are not specified in `settings.py`. I can't imagine your case when you want to make the app unavailable from `urls.py`.

A solution to your problem can be using a version control system like git and using multiple branches. Delete the app in the branch where you don't need the app.